# Зачем нужны тэги: leftmargin, marginheight, link,..

Tags: html

И как их применять?

```
leftmargin="0" 
topmargin="0" 
marginheight=0 
marginwidth=0 
rightmargin=0 
bottommargin=0 
link="#000000" 
vlink="#000000" 
alink="#000000"
```

Comment: Не применяйте их.

Comment: Это не теги, а **атрибуты**. К примеру, первый - [leftmargin](http://htmlbook.ru/html/body/leftmargin). Там же можете и про другие почитать. А по поводу **применения** - вам уже ответил @Genson

Comment: marginheight=0 marginwidth=0  

Вот эти и мне интересны... Это padding, что ли?

Comment: издалека напоминает `margin` все же :) да и используется это вроде только в `iframe`/`frame`

Comment: @thunder, да [так и есть](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe/marginheight).P.S. Споймал себя на мысли, что проматривая эти атрибуты, было ощущение, что вернулся во времена Win98 )))

Comment: 3.5 Verbatim c дровами на 3-клавишную мышь (какой скролл, о чем речь!)

Answer (score 5):

Прочитать! Например на сайте [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/) и применять. Но лучше не применять. Использовать CSS.

ps: а вообще идите читайте основы `HTML`, чтобы не задавать глупых вопросов.

Comment: а зачем столько !!! ставить?

Comment: чтобы наглядно было же как не надо делать...

зыж хотя сарказм видимо вам не понятен :)

Comment: @hesusmordino: это подколка для ТС, который тоже не экономит на вопросительных знаках. _Ваш КО._

Comment: @VladD спасибо :))))